# Hide certain fields Django Filter Forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter

I have been searching around a bit but I can't find the answer.

**search.html**

```
<form action="" method="get">
    {{ filter.form|crispy }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

filters.py

```
class GameFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    popularity = django_filters.RangeFilter()

    class Meta:
    
        model = Game
        fields = ['gamemodes']
        together = ['name', 'releases__date']
```

I still want to be able to search on those fields, but I dont want to show certain fields in the filter.form. Example, I want to be able to search on popularity, but I dont want its field generated in the filter.form. Currently all fields are being shown

How do I do that?

Comment: If you don't render the field how would the user filter that? Manually typing it in the url?

Comment: For example the name filter, I only use in the navbar, if they search for that, they come to a dedicated searchpage. Then I dont want to show the search field in that page. "name" is thus only accesible by another field (in this case just generates the url)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by manually posting the fields I want

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ filter.form.popularity |as_crispy_field }}
</div>
```